# void method (void *pixels); to delphi declaration

Tags: delphi

How should such declaration be converted to delphi?

```
void method (void *pixels);
```

And I have also the information that I should pre-allocate that variable.

could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Methods for C to Pascal conversion can be found here: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,12763.msg66330.html#msg66330.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to stick to the original declaration format (as for example when converting C DLL headers), and the conversion would be:

```
procedure method(pixels: Pointer);
```

You can find dome more information on converting C headers to Delphi [here](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm)

On the other hand, if you are converting the whole method or class you might want to adapt it to a more Delphi-like code. I do not know what "pixels" is, so I can hardly guess which would be the best option.

On a wild guess, if it is a matrix with some information about each pixel (position, color, alpha channel?) you can easily handle such a structure like that with object lists or create your own class to handle it.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that pixels points to an array of pixels, you could do:

```
procedure method(var pixels); cdecl;
```

If you passed pixels as ***untyped*** parameter, it is implicitly passed as pointer, which is what the C declaration does too, so the conversion matches the original perfectly. Using an untyped pointer enables you to cast it to anything you like or take its address to get the pointer. As long as you know the structure of pixels, that may be more convenient:

Let's assume pixels is a fixed size array of byte, where each bit is a pixel:

```
type
  TPixels = array[0..7] of Byte;

const
  Grey: TPixels = ($55, $AA, $55, $AA, $55, $AA, $55, $AA);

procedure method(var pixels); cdecl;
begin
  Move(Grey, pixels, Sizeof(Grey));
  // ...
  TPixels(pixels)[3] := $FF;
  // ...
```